# Coovachilli can't read encrypted password on RADIUS table

Tags: radius

I've installed and configured Coovachili with FreeRADIUS.
Everything is working well, the user can get captive portal before browsing the internet.

But I have a problem:  in the RADIUS table, the  password field is unencrypted.  When I try to encrypt the password field with md5 or sha1 Coovachili can't read it.

I want the radius password to be encrypted and Coovachili to read authentication from it.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

depends upon what authentication module you use in RADIUS